# Pulling in relational database fields

Tags: php, mysql, relational

So here's my problem. I have three tables:

Person Table

`person_id, name`

Events Table

`event_id, event_name, event_date`

Matches Table

`match_id, person_a, person_b, winner, event`

So in the matches table, person_a, person_b, and winner are integers that correspond to person_id in the Person table.

If I pull in a row from Matches table, it would come out like this:

`1, 1, 2, 1, Chess Tournament #33`

How can I lookup those 3 fields (person_a, person_b, and winner) with the Person table to pull in their actual names so that the result is?

`1, John, Steven, John, Chess Tournament #33`

I looked into joining the two tables, but it doesn't makes sense because I can't just do ON id=id, or WHERE id=id. I appreciate any help.

Comment: Foreign keys in your database schema would be helpful

Comment: I can make person_a, person_b, and winner fields have foreign keys to person_id, but they'll still pull in as 1, 2, 3, etc...

Comment: Whoops, my bad. I missed that part. Reading SO on a phone can get a bit confusing haha.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT
  Matches.match_id AS match_id,
  PersA.name AS persa_name,
  PersB.name AS persb_name,
  IF(winner=person_a,PersA.name,PersB.name) AS winner_name,
  Events.event_name AS event_name
FROM
  Matches
  INNER JOIN Person AS PersA ON Matches.person_a=PersA.person_id
  INNER JOIN Person AS PersB ON Matches.person_b=PersB.person_id
  INNER JOIN Events ON Matches.event=Events.event_id
WHERE
  -- whatever
```

Comment: Cool beans, that works flawlessly.  Seems like so much work though. lol.  You'd think there would be a simpler way since the fields are relational.